# How to I empty an array in the state before updating it gain?

Tags: javascript, react-native, setstate

I want to empty the array in the state before adding to it again

```
this.state = {
    arrayOne = [
    {
        name: 'first n',
        last: 'last n'
    },
    {
        name: 'first Name',
        last: 'last Name'
    }
]
}

this.setState({arrayOne: []}) //not emptying the array
this.setState({arrayOne: [...arrayOne.splice()]}) //also not working
```

Comment: `this.setState({arrayOne: []})` should work fine - if you're not getting the results you expect, you need to share more code and explain what's not working. Please edit your question with a better description.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you say its not working? The syntax looks fine and should work

Please note that setState is an **async** function, you need to **wait** for the update to complete in order to see change.

You can pass a callback function to setState, that will get executed when the state was set, like so

```
  this.setState({
       blah: 'something new'
    }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.blah) // will print 'something new'
 } 
})
```

You will **not** see immediate change if you do it like this:

```
this.setState({
   blah: 'something new'
})
console.log(this.state.blah) // this will print whatever 'blah' was previously set to, and not 'something new'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
this.state.arrayOne = [];
or
this.state['arrayOne'] = [];
```

Comment: Do not set state like this, it will not cause a re-render, which causes the state to be useless. you need to use setState

Comment: Thanks for your detailed info, but I hope this to helps someone who doesn't need a re-render!! @DanielB.

Comment: setting state without a re-render defeats the purpose of React

Comment: While this may be an answer to OP's problem, code-only answers are [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on StackOverflow. Please consider adding some explanation to the code provided as it will benefit both OP and future visitors.